# Django: How to lock a Boolean field for futher updates once set to True?

Tags: django, django-models, django-3.0

I'm wondering, I am managing a transition between two systems - and in one system I am using Django as the ORM and API backend.

I have a field that I want to set to True, and once it is set to True, it stays True. Even if the update from the older legacy system wants it to be False.

Is there a Django way to do this? Maybe overriding the `save()` method?

Comment: You can override the save() method and add an if statement checking the current value of your boolean.

Comment: Hi @TonyKyriakidis , so in the save() method - `if self.boolean: self.boolean = True` ?

Comment: Yes, if that doesn't work you can try using pre_save: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-save